# Is building a website for non-Muslim restaurants halal?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, food, work, internet

I have in minds an idea: I would like to launch a project which is a website where restaurants can show up their menu and people can buy and order them directly online.

However I can't control what these restaurants are adding. And what their offering are, so they might sell meals with pork meat or alcohol as well as they can sell fish meals and other allowed food.

I profit by taking a small margin after the restaurant owner agreed on each transaction between the user and the restaurant.

Am I allowed to do that? If no can I just charge for halal ordered meals?

Answer (score 2):

The ruling on such matters usually is that if the majority of the transactions carried out are halal then a small share of haram is tolerable (provided that you personally are not involved in the haram activity, and do your best to segregate the revenue from such activities and distribute the tainted portion of revenue as charity without hope of recompense).

From https://islamqa.info/en/101775

> Renting a shop to someone who sells permissible goods in it, such as
>   men’s perfumes for example, and other goods that may be used for
>   halaal or haraam purposes, such as cosmetics, depends on what is
>   usually the case. If most of the products are of the second type, and
>   most of the people in that country use them for haraam purposes, then
>   it is not allowed to rent the shop to a person to whom this applies,
>   so that you will not be helping in something haraam, because Allaah
>   says (interpretation of the meaning):
>
> ...
>
> But if what usually happens is sale of permissible goods in the
>   permissible manner, then it is permissible to rent the shop, based on
>   the usual situation, and so as to ward off hardship and difficulty,
>   because most sellers cannot avoid selling things that may be used for
>   halaal or haraam purposes.